# transition UICollectionView layouts with a layout delegate

Tags: ios, layout, delegates, uicollectionview

I am attempting to transition from one layout to another using useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions.

However, the delegate of the collectionView is not changed to the new view controller until the transition is complete, meaning that I cannot override flow layout hooks for itemSize, spacing, etc.  I presume this would be a problem on the pop animation, as well.

Is there a recommended way of doing this, or should I not be relying on delegate hooks?  When doing layout-to-layout pushes that do not require delegate hooks, things work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I arrived at was to implement a custom layout that does exactly what I want without requiring a delegate.  This proved to be difficult since UICollectionViewFlowLayout does not have hooks to, essentially, perform the role of the delegate without having a delegate (override size of headers, items).

The cheap and dirty fix was to grab a copy of PSTCollectionViewFlowLayout, modify it to work with UICollectionView (since it's part of a drop-in replacement package for UICollectionView), and then put in my hacks to do what I wanted to do.

I now have a UICollectionViewController to UICollectionViewController transition that looks similar to the weather app, but works on a UINavigationController stack automatically.  You tap a section to expand ONE section - the rest are sized to height = 0.

The first UICollectionViewController has a UICollectionViewFlowLayout and the second UICollectionViewController has a modified PSTCollectionViewFlowLayout with an 'expandedSection' property.